# Memory leak doctrine

Tags: symfony, memory-leaks, doctrine, batch-processing

I try to iterate on 100K users and i've got memory leak in my command script i try all thinks to clear memory but it doesn't work

So :

```
    gc_enable();

    $categories = $this->categoryRep->findAll();

    foreach($categories as $category){

        $nbUsers    = $this->userRep->countUserCategoryNotLinked();
        $pages      = ceil($nbUsers/self::BATCH_SIZE);
        $output->writeln($nbUsers.' users without category links');

        $progress              = new ProgressBar($output, $nbUsers);
        $progress->start();

        for ($i = 0; $i < $pages; $i++) {

            $users = $this->userRep->getUserCategoryNotLinked(($i*self::BATCH_SIZE) , ($i+1)*self::BATCH_SIZE);

            /** @var User $user */
            foreach ($users as $user) {

                if ($user->getCodeCategory() == $category->getCodeCategory()) {
                    $user->setCategory($this->categoryRep->find($category->getId()));
                    $this->em->persist($user);
                }

                $user = null;
            }

            $progress->advance(self::BATCH_SIZE);
            $event = $stopwatch->lap('link');
            $output->writeln(' links added ... | - Memory : ' .number_format($event->getMemory() / 1048576, 2) . ' MB - Time : ' . number_format($event->getDuration() / 1000, 2) .' seconds');

            $this->em->flush();
            $this->em->clear();
            $users = null;
            gc_collect_cycles();
        }
    }

    $progress->finish();
```

The memory leak when i get paginated users here :

```
$users = $this->userRep->getUserCategoryNotLinked(($i*self::BATCH_SIZE) , ($i+1)*self::BATCH_SIZE);
```

And here is my query paginated :

```
public function getUserCategoryNotLinked($offset,$limit)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.category IS NULL')
            ->setFirstResult($offset)
            ->setMaxResults($limit);
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

I don't understand i try to detach clear unset = null, but it still memory leak when i get users :(

If someone got an idea ?

Comment: You could add to your request `->andWhere('u.code_category = :category')` to filter results and avoid retrieving the whole database when you only need a few rows. BTW why did you set `$user = null` ?

Comment: Try $this
->_em
->getConnection()
->getConfiguration()
->setSQLLogger(null); at the top

Answer (score 0):

i make a mistake here :

```
 $users = $this->userRep->getUserCategoryNotLinked(($i*self::BATCH_SIZE) , ($i+1)*self::BATCH_SIZE);
```

Because pagination is not like this with doctrine it's not an offset but a page it's like this

```
$users = $this->userRep->getUserCategoryNotLinked($i , self::BATCH_SIZE);
```